# Troubles with IntelliSense in MacVim and Coc

Tags: c++, vim, clang, macvim, clangd

I'm trying to setup Vim as a C++ IDE on Mac. I followed [this tutorial](https://unkertmedia.com/how-to-setup-vim-for-c). So I'm using Coc and coc-clangd extension.
Everything works perfect, except 2 things :

- when I try to use **c++ standard libs** (stdio.h works for exemple but not iostream).
  It says it doesn't found the header file.
- when I try to include **custom header** files stored in the "include" folder of my project. It says the same.

**What I have tried :** *(.clangd file)*

```
CompileFlags:
  Add: [-I/absolute-path-to-include-folder]
  Compiler: clang++
```

This solved the second problem, even if **I would prefer relative path** (relative path didn't seem to work). But changing compiler from clang to clang++ didn't solve the first one. I would like to try with compile_flags.txt or compile_command.json but I don't find enough documentation. Besides I build my project with Makefile and not CMake.

Any idea?

Comment: Use the blog's comment section.

Comment: Note that `stdio.h` is part of the C standard library and **not** of the C++ standard library. The corresponding file of C++ standard library would be `cstdio`. It's not completely clear from your question if you noted so I thought I'd point it out.

Comment: For standard library headers, I recommend using [--query-driver](https://clangd.llvm.org/guides/system-headers#query-driver). For generating compile_commands.json for a project using `make`, have a look at [bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear) (see "Other build systems, using Bear" under https://clangd.llvm.org/installation#compile_commandsjson).